# Get Keys of an Array Error & Stream Conditions

Tags: java, collections, compiler-errors, java-8, java-stream

I want to get the keys from an array and put them into a `List`.

```
V[] values;
private List<K> getVals (){
 return  IntStream.range(arr.length/2,arr.length).filter(i-> arr[i]!=null && i%2==0 ).collect(Collectors.<K>toList());}
```

When I am compiling that code I get the error:

```
IntStream cannot be applied to the given types.
```

I knew, since it is an `IntStream` I get ints in my List, right? And my type is K, but even if don´t use generics, nothing changes.

2nd question:

I would like to know how it's possible to iterate over that array 
and set Data on an specified index. 
But with the condition that if on that index is already an value I recalculate the key.
Lets say I want to write something like:

```
if (arr[i]==0) {
    // do something and return
} else {
    // do something else and return
}
```

I don't get what's wrong here. I am using the same code as on some internetpages.

Comment: What do you mean by keys ? There is no key in an array, nor in a list

Comment: I got no idea what you're trying, but e.g. `i%==0` does not even exist.

Comment: I didn´t copy n pasted the code, so there can be some syntax errors, but the real Code is correct

Comment: okay, done. Don´t see how this makes it clearer :O

Comment: Well, because as @Bubletan said, `i%==0` made no sense. That makes your question not taken seriously

Answer (score 0):

You are using the type `K` in your lambdas but the array has the type `V`. I don' know where these types come from in your cod, but obviously they are not compatible. To compile this, you should have `V extends K`.

Comment: I am sorry. I am using an Function to calculate from the K an Integer value and that´s my index :)

Comment: I have an Method private int calc(K b) which takes different kind of Components and calculates from them an int value. This int value is used as index in the array.

Comment: That does not tell me who is `V`

Answer (score 0):

For your first question,

```
List<K> getVals() {
    return IntStream.range(arr.length/2, arr.length)
        .filter(i -> arr[i] != null && i%2 == 0)
        .collect(Collectors.<K>toList());
}
```

This doesn't work because the output of `filter` is an `IntStream`, which doesn't have a single-arg `collect` method. If you want to collect to a `List` you need to convert the `int` values from the `IntStream` into objects of reference type. I don't know how you get a value of `K` from your array. Is `K` the element type of `arr`? If so, then you should use `mapToObj` like this:

```
List<K> getVals() {
    return IntStream.range(arr.length/2, arr.length)
        .filter(i -> arr[i] != null && i%2 == 0)
        .mapToObj(i -> arr[i])
        .collect(Collectors.<K>toList());
}
```

If this works, you probably don't need the type witness `<K>` in your `Collectors.toList()` call.

For your second question, you can conditionally set elements of an array using `Arrays.setAll`:

```
int[] arr = ... ;
Arrays.setAll(arr, i -> arr[i] == 0 ? compute() : arr[i]);
```

This is basically a shorthand for running an `IntStream` over the array indexes. In fact, that's how it's implemented.

Alternatively, you write out the `IntStream` over the array indexes, filter out indexes you don't want to assign, and do the assignment within `forEach`:

```
IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
    .filter(i -> arr[i] == 0)
    .forEach(i -> arr[i] = compute());
```